# Multiple subdomains on intranet

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, subdomain

I'm creating a php application that runs on my intranet. let's say I have a web server that serves the domain `http://domain.com`. There is already an application on a subdomain called `http://app1.domain.com`

Can I create another sub domain called `http://app2.domain.com`?

Comment: Yes, if you can set the DNS record, or have someone do it for you, then you can have a single server respond for many different domains.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add as many sub domains as you wish. You can even do sub sub domains if you wanted to.